# How show all hour when I put slotMinutes each 15 min in fullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I has a fullcalendar, I set slotMinutes to 15 minutes but in the calender's hours only display 7am ... 9am (when it should display 7:15am, 7:30am...). However for slotMinutes:20 or slotMinutes:05, it work fine.

My Code:

```
calendar = $('#resultCalender').fullCalendar({
                        theme: false,
                        slotMinutes: 15,
                        events: result.CalendarDtos,
                        header: {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                        },
                        selectable: true,
                        selectHelper: true,
                        firstDay: 1
```

...
}

the hours in the calender for slotMinutes: 15, should display 7am, 7:15am, 7:30am... but it only display 7am, 8am, 9am....
If I set slotMinutes: 10, it work fine, it display 7am, 7:10am, 7:20am ...)

Any idea?

Comment: Can you show us the code your using at the moment please :)

Comment: I can has fullcalendar jquery?

Comment: u can add u r code in  http://jsfiddle.net